# Is multiplayer possible between XCOM Enemy Unknown and XCOM Enemy Within?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Is it possible for a player with XCOM Enemy Unknown to play multiplayer with another player with XCOM Enemy Within?

Answer (score 5):

**No, there is no cross-game play between the two.** Both players would need to be playing either Enemy Unknown or Enemy Within.

[2K community post for reference](http://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?266846-XCOM-Enemy-Within-FAQ)

> Console: Will players of Enemy Unknown Multiplayer be allowed to play together with players from Enemy Within?
>
> No, they are separate Multiplayer experiences.